# In WinRT How do I encode a png but keep it in memory as an in memory bmp instead of writing it to a file?

Tags: c++, winapi, rust, windows-runtime

The following code creates a bmp from a raw vector of bits and saves it to a file.
Since I only really want to have the bitmap stored in memory and manipulate it from there (ie get values of a the colours at certain pixels), how would I go about modifying this code to just have the image in m emory so that other image processing libraries can access the bmp?

Currently I save the image to a file, and then load that file back in using another library, but seems the file saving stage is a bit redundant?

While this example is in rust, i'd be fine with c++ code too.

```
let path = std::env::current_dir()
    .unwrap()
    .to_string_lossy()
    .to_string();

  let folder = StorageFolder::GetFolderFromPathAsync(path.as_str())?.get()?;

  let file = folder
    .CreateFileAsync("screenshot.png", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting)?
    .get()?;

    let stream = file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode::ReadWrite)?.get()?;
    let encoder = BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder::BmpEncoderId()?, stream)?.get()?;

  encoder.SetPixelData(
    BitmapPixelFormat::Bgra8,
    BitmapAlphaMode::Premultiplied,
    (item_size.Width - 18) as u32,
    (item_size.Height - 18) as u32,
    1.0,
    1.0,
    &bits,
  )?;

  Ok(())
```

Comment: Why do you create a BMP file with a `.png` extension?

Comment: "_load that file back in using another library_" → what other library? It probably has a way to create an image directly from your `bits` data.

Comment: @Jmb whoops, i used to create a png, but i switched to saving it as a bmp but just forgot to change the extension. Thanks i will look at the other libraries and see what options they have for loading in data.

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, that exactly what I needed. It indeed has a way to create  the image directly from the `bits` data!

Answer (score -1):

> Currently I save the image to a file, and then load that file back in using another library, but seems the file saving stage is a bit redundant?

Encode to a [`MemoryStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream) instead of a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream).

Comment: Those types are part of .NET, not the Windows Runtime. The respective (native) stream types reside in the [Windows.Storage.Streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams) namespace.